# how to automate using rancher cli for updating docker image tag in deployment

Tags: docker, kubectl, rancher-2

We have some dev and qa k8s clusters managed using rancher.
Every production release our team uses the rancher web ui to change the image tag version and update the app.
We want to automate this process based on the app name for which we need to create a new release.
Please suggest anyway for automating this. I asked question to chatgpt but it gave a simple rancher cli command like below in which it is using the `rancher kubectl` command to apply the manifest file.

`sed -i 's|old-image:tag|new-image:tag|' deployment.yaml`
`rancher kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml`

This approach does not seem a proper way, is there any better practice followed?

Thanks